# res.send function doesn't work with roll function

Tags: java, node.js, express, console.log

I want to call `res.send` function with the `roll` function inside but it doesn't work. If I'm log it with console.log(), it works.

```
res.send(roll(serverSeed, `${clientSeed}-${nonce}`));

console.log(roll(serverSeed, `${clientSeed}-${nonce}`));
```

This is what I want to return on my express website.

Comment: What is `roll(serverSeed, ${clientSeed}-${nonce})`, as in what's the output? are you trying to send some JSON or a html template? If you could provide some more detail that would be helpful, as a side note have you tried assigning the output of `roll(serverSeed, ${clientSeed}-${nonce})` to a `const` just before the send and pass that through instead? difficult to answer here without more information

Comment: Please include `roll` function in the Question.